# How to dynamically add SELECT statements if not enough results?

Tags: mysql, optimization

I am querying a table for a set of data that may or may not have enough results for the correct operation of my page.

Typically, I would just broaden the range of my SELECT statement to insure enough results, but in this particular case, we need to start with as small of a range of results as possible before expanding (if we need to).

My goal, therefore, is to create a query that will search the db, determine if it got a sufficient amount of rows, and continue searching if it didn't. In PHP something like this would be very simple, but I can't figure out how to dynamically add select statements in a query based off of a current count of rows.

Here is a crude illustration of what I'd like to do - in a SINGLE query:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(`id`) FROM `blogs` WHERE `date` IS BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-01-02' LIMIT 25

IF COUNT(`id`) < 25 {
    SELECT * FROM `blogs` WHERE `date` IS BETWEEN '2011-01-02' AND '2011-01-03' LIMIT 25
}
```

Is this possible to do with a single query?

Comment: Do you understand that first query will always return COUNT <= 20?

Comment: haha good point, sorry that was a typo...ill edit now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 possible solutions:

1. Compare the count on the programming language side. And if there is not enough - perform one more query. (it is not as bad as you think: query cache, memcached, proper indexes, enough memory on server, etc - there are a lot of possibilities to improve performance)
2. Create stored procedure

Comment: okay...so maybe not horrible to have extra queries....even if it ends up being 4-5 extra to fill in the extra rows?

Comment: @johnnietheblack: well, i would offer then preventive request the more rows than you need. For example - query rows for 3 days once. If there were no enough rows in 1st or 2 days - then 3rd will cover your needs, and you can always trim unneeded rows. And this wouldn't decrease performance dramatically. Anyway, you can also create another question about specific query performance, with additional `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and other useful details.